# Is there a way to ignore "XXX" while parsing data?

Tags: php, character, preg-match

I have a php script that brings back movie titles and ratings. It also sorts the data so that the movie titles with "xxx" show up at the bottom. Is there a way to completely ignore the "XXX" titles so they don't show at all, if someone doesn't want to see them on the screen? I'd still like it to sort with the XXX titles, but if I could include some code on the fly if someone doesn't want it that would be the the most efficient in my case. Any help on this is appreciated.

```
foreach (glob('mov/Alene*.mov') as $filename){ 
    $theData = file_get_contents($filename) or die("Unable to retrieve file data");
}

$string = $theData;
$titles = explode("\n", $string);

function getInfo($string){
    $Ratings = ['G', 'PG', 'PG-13', 'R', 'NR', 'XXX'];
    $split = preg_split("/\"(.+)\"/", $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE); 
    if(count($split) == 3){ 
        preg_match("/(".implode("|", $Ratings).")\s/", $split[0], $matches);
        $rating = $matches[0];
        return ["title" => $split[1], "rating" => $rating];
    }
    return false;
}


$infolist = array();
foreach($titles as $title){
    $info = getInfo($title);
    if($info !== false){
    $infolist[] = $info;
    }
}

usort($infolist, "infosort");

function infosort($lhs,$rhs) {
  return strcmp($lhs['rating'], $rhs['rating']);
}

foreach ($infolist as $info) {
        echo "<div style ='margin-bottom: 3px; text-align: center;
          font:13px Verdana,tahoma,sans-serif;color:green;'> 
           {$info["title"]} : {$info["rating"]}</div>";
}
```

Comment: If you can sort on some criteria it is certainly a trivial task to then not display based on that same criteria - i.e. `if ($info['rating'] !== 'XXX') { // display it }`

Answer (score 1):

Like so...

```
foreach ($infolist as $info) {
     if($info["rating"]!=="XXX"){
        echo "<div style ='margin-bottom: 3px; text-align: center;
          font:13px Verdana,tahoma,sans-serif;color:green;'> 
           {$info["title"]} : {$info["rating"]}</div>";}
}
```

Or better yet....do it at the source, then your array doesn't even include the XXX films.

```
 function getInfo($string){
    $Ratings = ['G', 'PG', 'PG-13', 'R', 'NR', 'XXX'];
    $split = preg_split("/\"(.+)\"/", $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE); 
    if(count($split) == 3){ 
        preg_match("/(".implode("|", $Ratings).")\s/", $split[0], $matches);
        $rating = $matches[0];
        if($rating!=='XXX'){
        return ["title" => $split[1], "rating" => $rating];}
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you just leave the foreach($infolist as $info) like normal :)

Comment: That isn't working. Have any other ideas? Still leaves all movie titles with xxx rating listed... :/

Comment: What exactly isnt working??  what happens if you echo $rating....between the line $rating=$matches[0] and if($rating...etc

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: What was the issue? Also...do you have the rep to accept..or not yet ;)

Comment: foreach ($infolist as $info) {if (preg_match('/XXX/', $info['rating'])) { continue; };